# React: Redux state updated in one effect but next effect in same component is using previous value of state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Using *react 16.8.2*, [hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Redux **initial state**:

```
const initialState = {
  name: one,
  count: 1,
}
```

**Component**:

```
function CompTwo(props) {
  useActiveCount(setActiveCount, 2); 
  useEffect(() => {
    // activeCount is still 1
    if(activeCount === 2) {
      setActiveName('two')
    }
  });
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  activeCount: state.count,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setActiveCount: count => dispatch(updateActiveCount(count)),
  setActiveName: name => dispatch(updateActiveName(name),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CompTwo);
```

**useActiveCount**:

```
const useActiveCount = function (setActiveCount, count) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveCount(count);
  })
}
```

In `CompTwo`, if I set count `useActiveCount(setActiveCount, 2);` before setting active name `setActivePage('two')`, shouldn't I get the new value `2`, in `activeCount` prop?

It does set `activeCount` to 2, when I check the state value in redux logger in dev-tool console, but in `useEffect` code of `CompTwo`, I still get older value of `activeCount` i.e `1`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: `setActiveCount: count => dispatch(updateActiveCount)`, shouldn't you pass updateActiveCount instead of count in the action ?

Comment: @UtsavPatel `updateActiveCount` is the action and it takes `count` as parameter. I updated.

Comment: Can you share a working codesandbox for your problem ?

Comment: actually you will see state updated in next render run. first time effect is called with previous value and next time with new value. do you have it differently?

Comment: just in case: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: @skyboyer I component is called only once, with `activeCount` equal to prev value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass activeCount to the `useEffect` hook or else it won't re-trigger the hook once the action has fully been fulfilled.

```
function CompTwo({ activeCount, setActiveCount, setActiveName }) {
  useActiveCount(setActiveCount, 2); 
  useEffect(() => {
    if(activeCount === 2) {
      setActiveName('two');
    }
  }, [activeCount]);
}
```

Runnable Example:

```js
// Custom hook

const useActiveCount = (setActiveCount, count) => {
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      setActiveCount(count);
    }, [count]
  );
};

// Redux types

const SET_ACTIVE_COUNT = "SET_ACTIVE_COUNT";

const SET_ACTIVE_NAME = "SET_ACTIVE_NAME";

// Redux actions

const updateActiveCount = count => ({
  type: SET_ACTIVE_COUNT,
  count,
});

const updateActiveName = name => ({
  type: SET_ACTIVE_NAME,
  name,
});

// Redux Reducer

const reducer = (state = { count: 0 }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_ACTIVE_COUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        count: action.count
      };
    case SET_ACTIVE_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.name
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);

// Comp 2

function CompTwo({ activeCount, activeName, setActiveCount, setActiveName }) {
  useActiveCount(setActiveCount, 2);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(activeCount);
    if (activeCount === 2) {
        console.log('hit');
        setActiveName('Two');
    }
  }, [activeCount]);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h5>Count: {activeCount}</h5>
        <h5>Name: {activeName}</h5>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  activeCount: state.count,
  activeName: state.name,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setActiveCount: count => dispatch(updateActiveCount(count)),
  setActiveName: name => dispatch(updateActiveName(name)),
});

const Comp = ReactRedux.connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CompTwo);

// App

const App = () => (
  <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
    <Comp />
  </ReactRedux.Provider>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/6.0.1/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Though I am using `useActiveCount`, I don't see any point in abstracting this logic as I am still calling this effect from each component that dispatches an action to set count.

Comment: @Harshvardhan the example only uses the code you supplied and does not detail on scopes outside of the question itself.

Comment: I didn't mean it that way. Analyzing the pattern of custom hooks I have used, I only want know if this is even required.

Comment: Yes I would honestly just dispatch the action in an useEffect that only gets run on the initial render.